# Cannot resolve symbol listView

Tags: java

I'm very new to java. I get the error cannot resolve symbol listView on the findViewById line. How do I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you define a `ListView` with the ID `listView` inside the layout file for the main activity?

Comment: I did not, how do I do that?

Comment: You should probably have a look at a tutorial for Android programming. [This](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) is the introduction concerning activities inside the "Build Your First App" tutorial from the official Android developer resources.